# How to get file sequence between two file paths

Tags: java, file

I got two files:

The first:

```
/opt/tmp/some_dir_1/some_dir_2/file_1.txt
```

and the second:

```
/opt/
```

Is there a pretty way in java to get files between them?

In result i need such a `List<File>`:

```
/opt/tmp/
/opt/tmp/some_dir_1/
/opt/tmp/some_dir_1/some_dir_2/
```

or a `List<String>`:

```
/tmp/
/some_dir_1/
/some_dir_2/
```

if files not inside each other, there can be some exception or `Collection.emptyList()` in result

Thanks!

Comment: The word 'between' makes no sense here. Do you mean "how can I get all files under /opt?"?

Comment: or get all parent folders of a given file?

Comment: @G00SE 

 I need all parent files of first file until i reach the second file

Answer (score 1):

This is classic looping style

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<File> files = new ArrayList<>();
    Path path1 = Path.of("/home/test/folder");
    Path path2 = Path.of("/home");
    if(!path1.startsWith(path2)){
        System.err.println("Path2 has to be a parent of path1");
        System.exit(-1);
    }
    while(!path1.equals(path2)){
        files.add(path1.toFile());
        path1 = path1.getParent();
    }
    System.out.println(files);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String strPath1 = "/opt/tmp/some_dir_1/some_dir_2/file_1.txt";
        String strPath2 = "/opt";

        Path path1 = Paths.get(strPath1);
        Path path2 = Paths.get(strPath2);

        List<String> inbetweenPaths = new ArrayList<>();
        List<File> inbetweenFiles = new ArrayList<>();

        if(path1.toFile().exists() && path1.startsWith(path2)) {
            Path tempPath = path1;
            while(!tempPath.getParent().equals(path2)) {
                tempPath = tempPath.getParent();
                inbetweenPaths.add(tempPath.toString());
                inbetweenFiles.add(tempPath.toFile());
            }
        }


        System.out.println(inbetweenPaths);
        System.out.println(inbetweenFiles);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[/opt/tmp/some_dir_1/some_dir_2, /opt/tmp/some_dir_1, /opt/tmp]
[/opt/tmp/some_dir_1/some_dir_2, /opt/tmp/some_dir_1, /opt/tmp]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute path to avoid null value from `getParent` in case the path provided is not absolute and has no parents **e.g.** `/some_dir_1`.

```java
public static void main(String args[]) {

        Path childPath = Paths.get("/opt/tmp/some_dir_1/some_dir_2/file_1.txt").toAbsolutePath();
        Path parentPath = Paths.get("/opt").toAbsolutePath();
        List<String> parents = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Checks if parentPath is indeed a parent of childPath
        if(childPath.startsWith(parentPath)){

            // Loop until parent of childPath and parentPath are equal
            while(!childPath.getParent().equals(parentPath)) {
                parents.add(childPath.getParent().toString());
                childPath = childPath.getParent();
            }
        }
        else {
            // throw Exception or set parent to empty array here
            System.out.println("ERR: parentPath must be a parent of childPath");
            return;
        }
        
        // Prints the output
        for(String p : parents) {
            System.out.println(p);
        }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
/opt/tmp/some_dir_1/some_dir_2
/opt/tmp/some_dir_1
/opt/tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the details of paths between directories is easily done by iterating from the parents of the path in a stream:

```
Path from = Path.of("/opt");
Path   to = Path.of("/opt/tmp/some_dir_1/some_dir_2/file_1.txt");
List<Path> items = Stream.iterate(to.getParent(), Objects::nonNull, Path::getParent)
                         .takeWhile(Predicate.not(from::equals)).toList();
System.out.println(items);

// Prints:
[/opt/tmp/some_dir_1/some_dir_2, /opt/tmp/some_dir_1, /opt/tmp]
```

You can map back the items as String (with `.map(Path::toString)`) or reverse the list as needed.